# Append html dynamically with unique id and remove the right one with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently able to append HTML and remove the right appended HTML, but when I add more of that HTML it is appended with the same id so the functionality if I want to show or hide a certain div element, is not working.

This is the code that i append and remove:

```
$(".adRowOutdoor").click(function(){
var newTxt = $('<div class="add-row-outdoor row width-100 padding-left-15"> <div class="form-group col-md-4"> <label for="state" class="control-label">Type</label> <div class="sg-select-container"> <select id="choose-outdoor"> <option disabled="">Choose type</option> <option value="Undercover walkway">Undercover walkway</option> <option value="Oval">Oval</option> <option value="Swimming Pool">Swimming Pool</option> <option value="Outdoor Basketing Court">Outdoor Basketing Court</option> <option value="other">Other</option> </select> </div> </div><!-- end col --> <div id="choose-outdoor-is-hidden" class="form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;"> <label for="other-textfield" class="control-label">Other</label> <input type="text" class="form-control form-input-field" name="other-textfield" value="" required="" placeholder=""> <span class="help-block"></span> </div> <div class="col-md-2 remove-btn-audit form-space-top-35"> <button class="btn btn-add-waste removeOutdoor"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle o-btn-add" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button> </div> </div><!-- row audit -->');
    $(".row-outdoor-container").append(newTxt);

});
$("body").on('click' , '.removeOutdoor' , function(){
      var curRow = $(this).parents('div.add-row-outdoor');
      curRow.remove();
});
```

An image how it looks is:
[image]

What I want now is to hide and show a div element with a text field on the selection of the certain div with a unique id that I want to generate.

I'm able to show that text field only for the first element, but not for other appended HTML.

```
$('#choose-outdoor').change(function (e) {
    var val = $("option:selected", this).val()
    if (val == 'other') {
        $('#choose-outdoor-is-hidden').show();
    } 
    // Hide complete sub type div
    else {
        $('#choose-outdoor-is-hidden').hide();
    }
});
```

JsFiddle of my code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Flamurbeqiri1/qeapy61q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `id` to `classes` so basically make `choose-outdoor` and `choose-outdoor-is-hidden` as your classes on the same elements.

Then use event delegation as the elements are dynamically created:

```
$('.row-outdoor-container').on("change", '.choose-outdoor', function (e) {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $el = $(this).closest(".add-row-outdoor").find('.choose-outdoor-is-hidden');

    if (val == 'other') {
        $el.show();
    } 
    else {
        $el.hide();
    }

});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeapy61q/1/)

Comment: This is better than using ids like I stated in my answer, but probably, he/she has to keep it as it is. It's better never to rely on ids.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev yea agree... but whatever OP wants to achieve can be done using ids.